AngularJS ng-repeat not working as expected
The ng-repeat works instantly, however, when data is changed programmatically, no changes occur on the html content.
HTML is as follows (index.html):
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>App</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
        
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="main-app-ctrl">
            <div ng-repeat="dt in data" ng-click="change_data();">
                <h1 ng-bind="dt"></h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>                           

AngularJS code (main.js):
let app = angular.module('app', []);

app.run(function($rootScope, $window){
    
});

app.controller('main-app-ctrl', function($scope, $window){

    $scope.data = [1, 2];

    $scope.change_data = function()
    {
        $scope.data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    };
});

I tried to use bind the data differently but still the data doesn't change. The HTML code is as follows:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>App</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
        
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="main-app-ctrl">
            <div ng-repeat="dt in data" ng-click="change_data();">
                <h1>{{ dt }}</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

And AngularJS code as follows:
let app = angular.module('app', []);

app.run(function($rootScope, $window){
    
});

app.controller('main-app-ctrl', function($scope, $window){

    $scope.data = [1, 2];

    $scope.change_data = function()
    {
        $scope.data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    };
});


Hei, I didn't find any issue with your code. I just used the same code to my code pen and finds it work. Please check https://codepen.io/jijocleetus/pen/abeGWmO
